# How to upload multiple users to firebase auth?

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase authentication, and I need to create above hundreds of User Accounts with email and password. Is there any way to do this without manually creating users in the console's website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use either the Firebase Admin SDK to create the user accounts, or use the Firebase CLI or Admin SDK to import them from a file.

With the Admin SDK you [can create the user accounts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user) through code like this:

> ```
> user = auth.create_user(
>     email='user@example.com',
>     email_verified=False,
>     phone_number='+15555550100',
>     password='secretPassword',
>     display_name='John Doe',
>     photo_url='http://www.example.com/12345678/photo.png',
>     disabled=False)
> ```

The above is for Node.js, but the SDK is also available for other platforms.

If you already have the users defined in a file somewhere, you can [import them through the Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/import-users) too, or by using the [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth).